# how to do nested select with group by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Please i have this table:

```
id| statut | datecreation
1 | appel  |10-09-2018
2 | message|10-09-2018
3 | message|11-09-2018
4 | message|11-09-2018
5 | appel  |12-09-2018
```

i want like this

```
date        |Nbappel |Nbmessage
10-09-2018  |   1    |1
11-09-2018  |   0    |2
12-09-2018  |   1    |0
```

Comment: Use a `sum` over a `case`, simply search for *conditional aggregation*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try :

```
SELECT datecreation as date, 
       SUM(case when statut='appel' then 1 else 0 end) as Nbappel,
       SUM(case when statut='message' then 1 else 0 end) as Nbmessage  
  FROM t
 GROUP BY datecreation
 ORDER BY datecreation;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e26d27/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select datecreation, 
       sum( statut = 'appel' ) as Nbappel, 
       sum( statut = 'message' ) as Nbmessage
from table t
group by datecreation;
```